# How to add an image inside the Terminal?

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

From what I've read it's not possible but I really don't see how to explain it any other way. PyGame changes the syntax structure a lot (I'm a beginner so I might be increasing things a bit) and what I really want is to program in pure Python.

My game is a Quiz and for each question an image should appear to illustrate.
As the game operates via terminal, I just wanted to be able to add the image and continue with the programming itself, without having to change my programming syntax. How can I print the images?

The game has a lot of texts and prints and if/ elses so im just want to continue with this sctructure but i'm here to learn!

[Game Screen Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6P5y.jpg)

*I've experience with programming and gamedev but learning Python!*

I already tried PyGame and trying TKinter right now to see how the things operates to make what i want to do to make.

Comment: If you want images in a terminal you can take a look at this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures   or this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35333/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-view-images-from-the-terminal   Then in the picture you mention you want to change the color of the terminal text. For this take a look at this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal

Comment: You should also post the code you have. Not all the ifs that you mention that you have, but a very minimal program that displays a picture and some text. Both PyGame and Tkinter are able to display pictures and text (but this is not using a terminal as you mention and tag in the question). Make a minimal program that does just this two things and show us what you have.

Comment: Finally, if your program has a lot of ifs and elses then it can probably be refactored. Take a look at python dictionaries and state machines. you can probably implement your logic as `{state1: {input1: response1, input2: response2}, state2: {input1: response1, input2: response2}}` you just need to code what each response does, and change the state accordingly

Answer (score 0):

the terminal is only text, unfortunately.
you could make your own tkinter or pygame script that would do it with guis.
you could also use ascii art but that is not recommended and would require a lot of experience